# How to use the output args of fun as the input args of jac in scipy.optimize.minimize?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm working with `scipy.optimize` library.

In the adjoint variable method, some of the resulted values from the objective function are needed to compute the jacobian.

Is that possible to use them in the jacobian function without using `global` variables?

For example,

```
def fun(x):
    '''
    something, something...
    '''
    # solving system equation. 
    u = spsolve(K,f)
    return u.dot(f)

def jac(x):
    '''
    something, something...
    '''
    # computing jacobian using the adjoint method
    return -(u.T@K@u).flatten()
```

In the `jac` function, `u` and `K` are necessary...
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a class with two callables, `fun` and `jac`, and store the intermediate results on the instance. I.e. `fun` fills in `self.u` and `self.K`, which `jac` uses.

Note however that this is brittle and give it a thought whether you really need this (that is, write it all with recomputing everything, check the profile, and if and only if these computations are a bottleneck, then OK, use a class or a global).

Comment: Thanks! I think a solving system of linear equations is the most time-consuming task. So re-using is necessary. By the way, because I'm not an Eng. speaker, I wonder: What do you mean by 'brittle?' I mean, I know the meaning of 'brittle' as an Eng. word. But, What does a code is brittle mean?

Comment: What I wrote, if implemented literally, depends on the order fun and jac are called. Call jac before fun and you get a jacobian from the previous fun call.